# Electron Temperature of a Gas Cloud

Tags: interstellar-medium, gas

Would a gas cloud made of HII and OIII have a higher electron temperature than a cloud just consisting of HII? I understand that electron temperature is the temperature of the electrons in a plasma, but what is the relation to metallicity and how does it work?

Comment: I don't understand your question. HII just means ionised hydrogen. OIII means doubly ionised oxygen. Are you asking whether you need a higher temperature to doubly ionise oxygen?